# How to use navigation architecture component to navigate dynamically

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-navigation

I have a use case and couldn't find an example of it online. So, my use case is I have a few fragments and the flow is decided by the server.Server returns a list of strings and based on the String, I have to navigate to a fragment. Eg:

Server returns ["detail_entry","accept_work","qr_code"] and depending on that I have to navigate using the navigation architecture component to DetailEntryFragment,AcceptWorkFragment or QRCodeScanningFragment. How to create Navigationaction directly in Kotlin code rather than use the navigation graph actions in xml.

I do not want to create an action between each and every fragment in xml and use it.I also want to mandate arguments passing. Is there any other way other of how to achieve this with the navigation architecture. I do not want to move to the old fragmentmanger and committing with them.

Comment: check the offical [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate#id), hope it helps

Comment: How can I mandate arguments while passing and do this at the same time.

Comment: The Graph can be 10 different fragments pointing to a common "home", it doesn't have to be all connected like a A->B->C->D.. so you can decide where you want to navigate to, and do it. For arguments, use the SafeArguments that Navigation provides and supply them... I don't see where you are exactly struggling with this. Please clarify what else you've tried.